# ¿como puede usar una constante dentro de un "template string" de php?

Tags: php

Me explico:

En PHP hay una forma de concatenar muy similar a los template sting de JS:

```
echo "El cliente {$nombre} es {$tipo}";
```

En este es facil concatenar una variable, pero con una constante es algo distinto.

Ya lo intente de las unicas formas logicas que se me ocurrieron(apenas estoy aprendiendo este lenguage):

```
define('estado', 'Basico');
echo "El cliente {$nombre} es {estado}";
echo "El cliente {$nombre} es {$estado}";
```

Y

```
const estado = "Basico";
echo "El cliente {$nombre} es {estado}";
echo "El cliente {$nombre} es {$estado}";
```

pero, si no salta un error, se plasma literalmente.

Se que es algo muy basico pero tengo curiosidad de saber como se haria.

Gracias!

Comment: En PHP hay muchas formas de formatear y mostrar un string, en estos casos te recomendaría usar [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). Lo cual quedaría como  `sprintf("El cliente es %s", 'nombre');` y así sucesivamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hay forma de usar una constante directamente dentro de un template string.
Existen [muchas formas creativas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203943/include-constant-in-string-without-concatenating) para que esto se pueda hacer, como asignando antes la constante a una variable, o por medio de una función.

Si es solo una constante, la forma más fácil es:

```
$cvalue = estado;
echo "El cliente {$nombre} es {$cvalue}";
```

Si son varias, se puede usar una función que retorne el valor de la constante:

Usando una [función anónima](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php) (Aunque puedes usar una función normal):

```
$prt_c = function ($var) {return $var;};
echo "El cliente {$nombre} es {$prt_c(estado)}";
```

[*] Por convención las [constantes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.php) se deben definir en mayúscula: `define('ESTADO', 'Basico');`. Esto es así en casi en todos los lenguajes.

Answer (score 2):

La forma más simple de hacerlo sería con `printf` (si quieres imprimir directamente) o con  `sprintf`  (si quieres guardar en una variable).

#### Ejemplo con [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php):

```
define('estado', 'Basico');
$nombre="abc";
printf("El cliente %s es %s",$nombre,estado);
```

**Salida:**

```
El cliente abc es Basico
```

#### Ejemplo con [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php):

```
define('estado', 'Basico');
$nombre="abc";
$str=sprintf("El cliente %s es %s",$nombre,estado); 
#sprintf es útil cuando interesa guardar una variable
#Por ejemplo cuando hay más lógica a determinar ...
$str.=$nombre==='abc' ? "\nNombre empieza por abc" : "\nNombre no empieza por abc";
echo $str;
```

**Salida:**

```
El cliente abc es Basico
Nombre empieza por abc
```